# How can I programmatically control a video texture frame?

Tags: texturing, shaders, video, drivers, shader-nodes

There are many different reasons why I might want to do this; but at the moment, I'm attempting to splice a complicated pre-rendered scene into a new one, so that the angle to the camera will control the frame of the video. (That way, I can "fake" an even more complicated scene with an older one.)

I know that I can add a texture to a shader, and set it to a video, for a video texture; I also know that I can set start and end frames. However, there are no feeds into these values—I can't just noodle the camera angle, with a little math, onto a frame input to solve the problem—and attempting to sync it by hand seems very inefficient.

So I can't wire it. There's no obvious way to add a driver, though it seems possible to copy a driver from the frame. I'm at the point of considering a color key and doing it in compositing, but this still seems way out of line.

Is it possible to control a video frame with an element of the scene like look-angle or position?

Comment: You can drive anything in a shader node-- right click in a value node or combineXYZ node and select "add driver".  You can also get camera space coordinates of the sample with a texture coordinates/object, or get camera depth with a camera info node.

Comment: @Nathan Yes, I'm aware I can do that—my concern is with the frame number and driving it, which does not have a driver option. You can copy from it, but not paste to it. So no, you can't drive literally anything.

Comment: Okay, now I understand.  But no, hard no, you cannot sample multiple frames of an animated texture with a single node.  This decision was probably made because the video memory usage would get insane really fast.  The best that you can do is mixRGB between multiple animated texture nodes-- possibly referencing the same video only with different offset/start frame.  Then, you can do whatever with the fac of that mixRGB.

Comment: @Nathan that's actually a great idea, and should probably be an answer! I'll experiment with that, and with color keying in the compositor like I've been doing.